# How to declare dictionary of dictionary of dictionaries in TCL?

Tags: dictionary, tcl

I am trying to declare dictionary of dictionary of dictionary in TCL but I am not able to go down to the 3rd level to create a key.

This is what I did to get a dictionary of dictionaries

```
set my_dict [dict create]

dict append my_dict "key1"

dict with my_dict {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    dict append "key1" "key2"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
}

puts $my_dict
>> key1 {key2 {}}
```

This is as expected. Now I need another level of dictionary within this as follows:

```
key1 {key2 {key3 {}}}
```

How can this be achieved?

I tried doing the following:

```
dict with my_dict {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    dict append "key1" "key2" "key3"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
}
```

But it returns the following:

```
key1 {key2 key3}
```

Comment: Are you thinking that `dict append` adds a key to a dictionary? It does not. It concatenates a string to the value of a dictionary key. This explains your "incorrect" output: you are appending the string "key3" to the value of `dict get $my_dict key1 key2` (which was an empty string before)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if I follow what you are trying to do; I'd do:

```
set my_dict [dict create]

dict append my_dict "key1"

dict with my_dict {
    dict append "key1" "key2"
    dict with key1 {
        dict append "key2" "key3"
    }
}

puts $my_dict
```

But I think the simplest using the dict commands is still:

```
set my_dict [dict create key1 [dict create key2 [dict create key3 ""]]]
```

If you don't want to simply do:

```
set my_dict {key1 {key2 {key3 {}}}}
```

Comment: Or simply `dict set my_dict key1 key2 key3 {}`.

Comment: Oh yea, that too

Answer (score 0):

The initial creation of that can be done with just:

```
dict set my_dict key1 key2 key3 {}
```

but appending to that interior dictionary is a little awkward. (Not all `dict` subcommands support nested dictionaries directly; there are just too many syntactic ambiguities to allow it to work.) This is where `dict update` is particularly useful:

```
dict update my_dict $key1 subdict1 {
    dict update subdict1 $key2 subdict2 {
        dict append subdict2 $key3 "foo bar"
    }
}
```

The advantage over `dict with` is that the latter expands out the whole dictionary and you don't have any real control over what variables get changed; `dict update` is selective in several ways (e.g., you can use variables with names not matching keys and you can only expand the keys you care about).